# Why does the Winds Aloft ‘For Use Time’ start before the ‘Valid Time’?

Tags: weather, winds-aloft

Why is it that a winds aloft forecast normally has a "valid time" that comes in the middle of the "for use" time range? Why don't they just state the valid time as the beginning of the for use time period?
[image: It says it is valid starting at 1800 but its for use time starts four hours earlier, why?]

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! To make your question as clear as possible, it would be helpful to add a specific example.

Answer (score 2):

> Wind and temperature aloft forecasts (FB) are computer-prepared and issued by the National Centers for Environmental Prediction (NCEP) at Suitland, Maryland. The forecasts are valid 6, 12, and 24 hours after the observation date/times of 0000Z, 0600Z, 1200Z, and 1800Z based on National Weather Service Instruction 10-812, Aviation Wind and Temperature Aloft Forecasts.
>
> Source: [FAA 7110.10](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/fs_html/chap8_section_3.html)

In essence, it's a subtle way of telling you it's a best guess based on observations and computer models, and it covers a time period where they think the model's conclusion will be closest to the real thing. Like medicine, weather forecasts are not an exact science.

Comment: I think my English is pretty clear.

Comment: Well, like, now it is 

Comment: Second, slower readings always seem to help, don't they...

Comment: I concur. The original wording was, however, not as clear as the edited one.

Comment: The wording of the last paragraph never changed. Anybody can see that. I consider this subject closed.

Comment: Anyone can see that the wording of the last paragraph *has* changed. Please see for yourself. I made the edit on Jul 24 at 8:28. If you wish, I can do a rollback.

Comment: Oh now I see what you did. And you think because you added "Just " to the beginning of that sentence, that justifies your bizarre comment? Are you kidding me? LOL! I am DONE with this dumb thread.

Comment: Well meanwhile my *bizarre* comment has been deleted, for one reason or another, so case closed. My comment was made in benevolent manner, but it obviously was readable as offensive, as is the case with any internet content these days.